# MySQL statement syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm experiencing problems with this MySQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Articoli (Cod_Articolo char(10) NOT NULL,
Des_Articolo varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Cat_Articolo char(2) NOT NULL,
Ubi_Articolo char(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Cod_Articolo)
FOREIGN KEY (Cat_Articolo) REFERENCES Categorie(Cod_Categoria) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 

corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY 

(Cat_Articolo) REFERENCES Categorie(Cod_Categoria) ON DELETE NO ACTI' at line 6
```

I don't see why...

Thanks, Mauro

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a comma here:

```
PRIMARY KEY (Cod_Articolo)
```

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Articoli (Cod_Articolo char(10) NOT NULL,
Des_Articolo varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Cat_Articolo char(2) NOT NULL,
Ubi_Articolo char(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Cod_Articolo),
FOREIGN KEY (Cat_Articolo) REFERENCES Categorie(Cod_Categoria) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: It works but I still get an error : ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'prova1.Articoli' (errno: 150)

Comment: What is the datatype of `Cat_Articolo` and of `Cod_Categoria`?